# Does any hardware RAID controller support hot expanding a unit to larger disks?

Tags: raid

I am wondering if the following is possible with *any* RAID card currently in existence. (Not interested in software RAID):

I start with a RAID 10 of 500 gig disks. (unit size is 1 TB) I want to swap in 1 TB disks, one by one, and migrate the size of the unit from 1 TB to 2 TB on the fly. Is this possible? If so, what controller(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with quality hardware RAID controllers.

- HP Smart Array controllers [absolutely support this](https://serverfault.com/questions/371117/what-are-the-good-ways-to-migrate-a-raid-array-to-bigger-disks/371131#371131).
- Dell PERC controllers do this.
- LSI RAID controllers can support this.
- Adaptec RAID controllers...

Others?

Of course, you need operating system support to recognize the newly-expanded array... So in most cases, a reboot can be required.